Creating Scorecard with Non Percent Metric and Percent Metrics
I am trying to create a weighted scorecard.
AHT (25%) - The higher the metric the "worse" the call agent is performing.
VOC (37.5%)- The higher the metric the "better" the call agent is preforming.
CSAT (37.5%) - The higher the metric the "better: the call agent is preforming.



AHT
VOC
CSAT
TOTAL




345
85%
78%



438
60%
92%




I get that for VOC and CSAT it would be multiplying the score by the weightage then summing together at the end to get the total. But how do I incorporate AHT into this calculation?



AHT
VOC
CSAT
TOTAL




345*25%=86.25
85% * 37.5% =32%
78% * 37.5% = 29.25%



438* 25%= 109.5
60% * 37.5% =22.5%
92% * 37.5% = 34.5%




Please let me know of any best practices you have for this type of weighted scorecard with these kinds of metrics!

Do you have any way of converting AHT to a percentage? For example, if these were standardized tests, you could take the AHT / [Maximum score] to do so.
